# Why it is possible to use moved variable

Tags: c++, c++11, move, compiler-warnings

Using a value after it has been moved can lead to erroneous code (MWE below). I understand that in cases where everything is copied, using the variable after a move is valid. However, it seems illogical to me to use that variable in such cases.

Are there situations where using a moved variable is a good idea? And if not, is it possible to set up a compiler warning for this?

```cpp
class A {
public:
  std::string *s;

  A() : s{new std::string{"A class"}} {}
  A(A &&a) : s{a.s} { a.s = NULL; }
  ~A() { delete s; }
};

int main() {
  A a1;
  std::cout << *a1.s << '\n';
  A a2{std::move(a1)};
  std::cout << *a2.s << '\n';
  std::cout << *a1.s << '\n'; // Segfault

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The _pointer_ `s` in the _moved-from_ object is still usable. You can create a new `string` that it can point to. However, what you are doing is normally not how it's done. You'd make `s` a normal non-pointer member variable, which would leave the _moved-from_ `s` in a valid but indeterminate state. You'd just need to `clear()` it and it would be ready to be used again.

Comment: For a user-defined type, you are allowed to leave a moved-from instance in whatever state you want to provide (*thanks Howard Hinnant for teaching me this!*).  Most standard C++ library objects are in a valid-but-unspecified state (suitable for re-assignment or destruction).  Some have additional guarantees post-move, like std::unique_ptr or std::vector.

Comment: The whole point of move semantics is that the moved-from object is *typically* going to disappear after the move, so you are stealing its data instead of copying it. In that case, it really doesn't make much sense to keep using an object that is been moved from. CAN you keep using it? That depends on the object's type. SHOULD you keep using it? Usually no.

Comment: Read up on [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).